# Where IIS is wasting time in a .net webapi response?

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-web-api, garbage-collection, iis-7.5

Context:
WebApiController calling business object (these business objects create & run a few threads to process data from different providers) and after join them, the webapi format some fields or add another ones: This is the skeleton of our tipical webapi controllers:

```
xxxxController: WebApiController
{
   StopWatch timer.Start()
   .
   .
   businessLogic //1.create cache of some tables (around 5000 rows, 5/10Mb.) 
                 //2.create and run threads (10 aprox)
                 //2.1 every thread call external services via APIs
                 //3.wait the join of all threads.
   .
   .
   timer.Stop()
   log(timer.elapsedMilisecond)
}
```

Up here, all perfect. The controller reponse is correct, the data are correct and everything is ok, BUT, when we're starting to measure times to improve the performance, we've realesed that the time we have measured inside the controller is much less than the time measured in the client, I explain it:

The AVG measured in the Controller are 30 sec. but the elapsed time measured in client (browser) is about 10-15sec. more:

- It's not due to download time (the response size avg is about 500kb)
- We think it's not due to seriralization issues (our first fail bet)
  (to ensure this we have forced some empty responses with 3/6kb and the elapsed time in the client is 10/15sec more than the controller-time yet).
  Example:

[Client time vs. WebApiController time for real and empty response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0y1k.png)

- Others controller follow the same skeleton (but with less cache requirement and parallels threads running), and we don't notice significat diference between apiController elapsedTime and client elapsedTime (perhaps some miliseconds or 1 sec, as much)

So my question is: where is IIS (or .NET) consuming that time??

- perhaps Garbagge Collector?? (for us, 10/15sec is a lot of time for GC, but maybe could be this?).
- perhaps Compressing the responses??? (500kb is very little size to spend so much time, isn't it?)
- some task in IIS that i don't know? any help?

I have analyzed the pipeline  of a webapi RQ, and sincerely, don't know where we are wasting that valuable time.
(https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf)

Someone know how to measure the time that the different activities that take place in the .NET framework or in IIS after the controller return?

thanks in advance!

EDIT:

[time detail in client side (chrome-dev-tool)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr3Wy.png)

Comment: Is your screen shot from Chrome Dev tools (network)? If so, click on the time bar (green or blue) to see the details. [This reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) will be helpful. Seeing 43s on 6kb payload isn't normal and unless you have some other (network, etc) issue isn't something I'd look at IIS nor ASP.Net for, I'd look into client side code/js, blocking calls, etc. Hth.

Comment: It might be helpful to figure out if that 10-15s is before or after (or some of both) the controller is hit. If it’s a lot of time before, it could be things like authentication/authorization.

Comment: many thanks to both,  I edit the original post to attach a breakdown of the times in clientside. And answering to Dave, this delay is always after the controller return.